# OpenJPA OptimisticLockException: Detaching object from one PersistenceUnit and saving it to another

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I get my domain objects from one database and then save them to another empty database. I'm using Spring Roo for the persistence layer, so I have minimal control over how the persisting is done (using merge vs persist).

When persisting, I get the exception:

> OptimisticLockException: Attempted to attach deleted instance type
>   "class xxx" with oid "xxx".  If the instance is new, the version field
>   should be left to its default value

Supposedly, I should be able to set the "pcVersionInit" field of the object to false, to have it persist anyway, but that doesn't work.

Any idea how to do this on the level of the domain object?

Comment: Does your Entity have a generated ID?

Comment: Yes, Rick: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: Even in you get the pcVersionInit field set correctly, you're going to have problems. Since you have the field marked as @GeneratedValue, OpenJPA assumes that the ID field will be empty and in your case, it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

Removing @GeneratedValue annotation on the Id field solved the problem. Thanks for the hint, Rick!